# Eigenvalue of Block matrix: Adjacency of complete bipartite Graph

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $A\in \{0,1\}^{mn \times mn}$ be the adjacency matrix of a complete bipartite graph with $m$ and $n$ vertices each, i.e. let $A$ be the matrix consisting of two blocks $A_1\in \{0,1\}^{m \times m}$ with zeros on the diagonal and 1 elsewhere, and $A_2 \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ likewise.

I know that the eigenvalues of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are given $m-1, -1, \dotsc, -1$ and $n-1, -1, \dotsc, -1$, respectively.

It seems as if there were an easy way to combine these to the eigenvalues of $A$, and I think that the eigenvalues of $A$ should be $\sqrt{mn}, 0, \dotsc, 0, - \sqrt{mn}$, but I am not sure how to get to this.

More general: How can one compute the eigenvalues of a block matrix given the eigenvalues of the blocks.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You seem to be confused with definition of complete bipartite graph. In adjacency matrix, there are no two such blocks. Diagonal blocks will be 0 and off diagonal will consist of all entries as $1$

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I could find 
"The eigenvalues of a disconnected graph
are just the eigenvalues of its components and
their multiplicities are sums of the corresponding
multiplicities in each component."
Hope this helps